# What happens without a binary semaphore

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, semaphore, binary-semaphore

Assume the code below demonstrating a binary semaphore example.

In this example, we have a pthread that reads the source.txt and attempts to copy the content to destination.txt while locking it using a binary semaphore.

What happens in the comment section below without the semaphore?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <filesystem>
#define _TIMESPEC_DEFINED
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <thread>
#include <valarray>

pthread_t StartFileAccessThread();
void *CopyFile(void *parameters);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread = StartFileAccessThread();

    void *returnValue;
    pthread_join(thread, &returnValue);

    getchar();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


pthread_t StartFileAccessThread()
{
    std::string sourcePath("source.txt");
    std::string destinationPath("dest.txt");
    sem_t semaphore;
    sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0);
    pthread_t thread;

    void *parameters[3];
    parameters[0] = &semaphore;
    parameters[1] = &sourcePath;
    parameters[2] = &destinationPath;

    pthread_create(&thread, nullptr, &CopyFile, parameters);

    // What happens without the binary semaphore?
    sem_wait(&semaphore);
    sem_destroy(&semaphore);

    printf("Freeing ressources.\n");

    return thread;
}


void *CopyFile(void *rawParameter)
{
    void **parameters = static_cast<void **>(rawParameter);

    sem_t *semaphore = static_cast<sem_t *>(parameters[0]);
    std::string sourcePath(*static_cast<std::string *>(parameters[1]));
    std::string destinationPath(*static_cast<std::string *>(parameters[2]));

    sem_post(semaphore);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    copy_file(sourcePath, destinationPath, std::experimental::filesystem::copy_options::overwrite_existing);

    printf("File copied \n");

    return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens in the comment section below without the semaphore?

Without the semaphore, function `startFileAccessThread()` may return before the new thread finishes (or starts) copying its parameters from the argument object.  That object is local to `startFileAccessThread()`, so its lifetime ends when that function returns. Undefined behavior results if the copy thread's accesses to it do not happen before that.

Comment: The usual way to do this would be for `StartFileAccessThread` to `malloc`/`new` the parameter block instead and for `CopyFile` to `free`/`delete` it when it's done with it. (The inner parameters would then either be objects instead of pointers or would also be allocated with `malloc` or `new`) I suspect this code just exists to demonstrate how to use a semaphore for this.

Comment: And note also that "happens before" is a technical term in this context, related to inter-thread synchronization operations.  Without the semaphore use or something sufficiently similar, its not, formally, a matter of any actual timing -- the copy thread's accesses to the argument object *definitely do not* "happen before" the end of that object's lifetime.